# How to include specific filename from multiple directories using PHP

Tags: php, include, filenames

I'm trying to include specific 'admin view' files from within a folder structure. I'm familiar with include/require or how to recursively include a folder, but all I need to do is include one filename from each directory - the admin_view.php file.

So, my dir. structure looks like this:

File to have includes is at root.

```
 - mods
  - type
    -- type1
       -admin_view.php
       -other files I do not need included
    -- type2
       -admin_view.php
       -other files I do not need included
    -- type3
       -admin_view.php
       -other files I do not need included
```

As you can see, recursively including the files wont work, and manually including them works fine,.. until we start adding and removing directories from the main 'type' folder.. then, we have to manually edit all the include codes.. so, I am hoping to find a function, or snippet, that will allow me to look through al the directories with the 'type' directory and include ONLY a specific filename (admin_view.php)

This is what I've pieced together so far, but it's not working... :(

```
$modulesDir = array (
    ROOT_DIR.'mods/type',

);
$view_name = "admin_view.php";

function __autoload($view_name) {
    global $modulesDir;
    foreach ($modulesDir as $directory) {
        if (file_exists($directory . $view_name)) {
                require_once ($directory . $view_name);
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much! This place is an awesome resource.. and I really appreciate all the knowledge, correction, clarification, etc. that it provides the development community!
J

**EDIT:**

I was able to get the view files loaded with this.. but I have a feeling that there's a better way to do this:

**CLARIFICATION**

I was misusing the __autoload function.. as I am NOT loading classes.. just php files to include in the main document... sorry for the error, I'm learning  :)

Comment: Well, I believe your solution is good enough :) Actually simpler than the other suggestions. Unless you have any specific problem with it, you should be fine.

Comment: ok.. if you cannot see any other (read: better) way to do it and there's not issue with the way it is now.. I will proceed with the version I've Frankenstein'ed .. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the only issue in your code, but check this out:

```
$modulesDir = array (
    ROOT_DIR.'mods/type',
);

if (file_exists($directory . $view_name)) { ... }
```

You're not ending your folder names in the `$modulesDir` with a `/`

When you do `file_exists($directory . $view_name)`, you're actually checking for a file named

```
ROOT_DIR.'mods/typeadmin_view.php'
```

and not what you wanted

```
ROOT_DIR.'mods/type/admin_view.php'
```

#### Edit:

Regarding the use of `__autoload($name)`, one thing to keep in mind is:

From [PHP Documentation: Autoloading Classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

> You may define an __autoload function
>   which is automatically called in case
>   you are trying to use a
>   class/interface which hasn't been
>   defined yet.

It means that if you're not using classes or if the classes you're using are already 'included', it won't be called.

From your question, it wasn't clear at first glance if you were using classes or not, even tho it looked like your use of `__autoload()` wasn't appropriate.

One way or the other, your approach of using `glob("/path/*/file.php")` seems good.
It is simple, clear and gets the job done.
Unless you find an specific problem with it, you should be good to go.

Comment: If he answered your question, click the check mark so he gets credit for it!

Comment: it was definitely a correction that was needed,. however from what I'm reading, I should be using something other than __autoload to load specific php files into another... but the catch is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Feel free to 'accept' the answer that you feel solved your problem (or no answer at all if you think none of them did it). But as a general rule, give upvotes to all the answers you felt were helpful. You should give upvotes not only on your questions but anytime you search for a problem and find a helpful answer. That's how the StackOverflow sorts the answers as well as giving credits to those taking the time to help. Anyway, hope you solved your problem! :)

Comment: @Carlos... I've tried to upvote those that were helpful.. but it says that I need a Reputation of 15 to do so.. :-/ Everyone on here has been very helpful, and I'm grateful for all the feedback.. hopefully soon I'll be able to show it, as my rep goes above 15.

Comment: So true. I forgot about that. First time I answered a question here I couldn't even put links on the answer because of reputation limit. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SPL's [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to iterate over all files in a directory and its subdirectories.
Then you can use a class extending [FilterIterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php) to limit the result to specific files.

e.g.

```
<?php
class EndsWithFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
  protected $s;
  public function __construct($s, $it) {
    parent::__construct($it);
    $this->s = $s;
  }

  public function accept() {
    $c = parent::current();
    return false!==stripos($c, $this->s, strlen($c)-strlen($this->s));
  }
}


$directory = 'type/';
$it = new EndsWithFilterIterator('admin_view.php',
  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory))
);
foreach($it as $f) {
  echo $f, "\n";
  // require_once $f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is used to auto load class includes.

It means everytime you create a new instance of a class that PHP doesn't know the definition yet, PHP will call the `__autoload` function and hope to get the class definition included.

I don't see any code creating an object in your code, if you take a look at the PHP of `__autoload`, they provide this sample.

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

If you are looking for including the view when you create the controller object something like this should work, your controller would have to be named like `foobarController` for this to work properly.

```
$modulesDir = array (
    ROOT_DIR.'mods/type',

);
$view_name = "admin_view.php";

function __autoload($class_name) {
    global $modulesDir;
    if(preg_match('/(\w+)Controller/', $class_name, $match)){
      $class = $match[1];
      // TODO: include the class definition
      // require CONTROLLER_DIR . $class_name . '.php';
      foreach ($modulesDir as $directory) {
        if (file_exists($directory . strtolower($class) . '_view.php')) {
                require_once ($directory . strtolower($class) . '_view.php');
                return;
        }
      }
    }
}

$adminController = new AdminController();
```

Comment: yeah but your view are not classes right, so why using `__autoload` ?